# How do I filter out punctuation symbols above number keys with RegEx?

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation, special-characters

I am trying to write code that prevents users from entering anything other than numbers into a input field.  Here is the code for this input field:

```
Const RegExDecimalOnly = "^(((\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(.\d+)?$"
```

This RegEx blocks alphabetical characters just fine, both uppercase and lowercase.  It also blocks many other punctuation characters.  However, it allows me to enter punctuation symbols that are produced when you hold down shift and press the numeric key.  These punctuation symbols include:

! [Generated by holding down the Shift key and pressing 1]

@ [Generated by holding down the Shift key and pressing 2]

The number sign [Generated by holding down the Shift key and pressing 3]

% [Generated by holding down the Shift key and pressing 5]

^ [Generated by holding down the Shift key and pressing 6]

& [Generated by holding down the Shift key and pressing 7]

An asterisk [Generated by holding down the Shift key and pressing 8]

( [Generated by holding down the Shift key and pressing 9]

) [Generated by holding down the Shift key and pressing 0]

I cannot use a RegEx of "^[0-9]*$" because the input field needs to have two digits after a decimal point, as well as commas to delineate thousands, millions, billions, and so on.  Any assistance anyone can provide me would be greatly appreciated.  Have a nice day.

Comment: Note you need to escape `.`: `^(((\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(\.\d+)?$` or it will match any character but a newline.

Comment: I think you should share all the relevant code.

Comment: Definitely escape that period like Wiktor said. Otherwise so long as there is one or more numbers before and after, any one character can be added (i.e. 3a5 or 4$5). Have you tried a [regex checker](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Any feedback? Or are you not interested in a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the MaskedEdit control? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733654%28v=vs.60%29.aspx